df = 1 for an intercept-only linear mixed model, how to fix? (R)
I'm testing the intercept of a linear mixed model regression predicting a binary variable in an intercept-only model with random intercepts for another dichotomous variable and one factor variable with >2 levels.
The summary stats have a df of 1, and this is a mistake --
here's the code:
library(lme4)
library(lmerTest)

dem_personal_intercept_lmer <- lmer(
  Personal_Vote ~ 1 + (1 | Dem_candidate_order) + (1 | dem_policy_order), 
  data = dems)
summary(dem_personal_intercept_lmer)

Which outputs:
Linear mixed model fit by REML. t-tests use Satterthwaite's
  method [lmerModLmerTest]
Formula: 
Personal_Vote ~ 1 + (1 | Dem_candidate_order) + (1 | dem_row_order)
   Data: dems

REML criterion at convergence: 1168.8

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-0.7827 -0.6058 -0.4799 -0.3877  1.9906 

Random effects:
 Groups              Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 dem_row_order       (Intercept) 0.001723 0.04151 
 Dem_candidate_order (Intercept) 0.003118 0.05584 
 Residual                        0.176786 0.42046 
Number of obs: 1043, groups:  
dem_row_order, 24; Dem_candidate_order, 2

Fixed effects:
            Estimate Std. Error       df t value Pr(>|t|)  
(Intercept) -0.26428    0.04245  1.08107  -6.226   0.0888 .

I also tried
summary(dem_personal_intercept_lmer, ddf = "Kenward-Roger")

which outputs:
Number of obs: 1043, groups:  dem_row_order, 24; Dem_candidate_order, 2

Fixed effects:
            Estimate Std. Error       df t value Pr(>|t|)  
(Intercept) -0.26428    0.04245  1.08429  -6.225   0.0884 .

the df ~1 here being the main mistake.
Why might this be happening?

Can you please be more specific which part of the summary you believe to be a mistake, and why? Even better if you can make this reproducible using e.g. lmer(mpg ~ 1 + (1 | am) + (1 | gear), mtcars) or similar. I am looking at the summary of that example, and don't see any degrees of freedom listed?

I'd also note that using a linear mixed model to predict a binary variable is unusual outside of economics (the linear probability model); furthermore, random effects with grouping variables with only two levels are very unlikely to work well.

It's hard to say exactly, but this represents a problem with the underlying theory/df approximation, not (AFAICS) a bug in the code. I can replicate your results, more or less (in the example below I get df of about 2).

the Satterthwaite and K-R approximations are approximations, and for some models they fail badly.
if you know what the df "should" be, you can stuff these into the tables/recompute p-values with those df ...
tangentially, it makes very little sense to treat a two-level factor as a random effect grouping variable (this is the equivalent of estimating a variance from two data points — theoretically possible, but practically not a good idea). If fit candidate order as a fixed effect instead (vote ~1 + dco + (1 | dro)), I get much more sensible answers for the df ...
I'd also, personally, question the use of the linear probability model, i.e. fitting a linear model to binary data — why not use a mixed logistic regression? (But I understand that econometricians and other stats-y people from social sciences have some strong positive opinions about the LPM, even if I don't share them ...)

library(lme4)
library(lmerTest)
n <- 1043
set.seed(101)
dd <- data.frame(id = 1:n,
                 dro = factor(sample(1:24, size = n, replace = TRUE)),
                 dco = factor(sample(1:2, size = n, replace = TRUE)),
                 y = 1)


y <- simulate(~1 + (1 | dro) + (1 | dco),
              newdata = dd,
              newparams = list(beta = -0.25, theta = c(0.2, 0.8), sigma = 0.5),
              seed = 102,
              family = gaussian)[[1]]
dd$vote <- as.numeric(y > mean(y))
m <- lmer(vote ~1 + (1 | dro) + (1 | dco), data = dd)
summary(m)  ## df = 2.12 
summary(m, ddf = "Kenward-Roger")  ## df = 2.149

